# check radio box list item value according to query results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

in edit form  I have a value of radio button  that im getting from my query , 
how ever the user need to c his selection checked & I he wants to change (change his selection) . SO I need to display the correct value selected & the other un check . the list is manual (not from the DB ) 
I need something like `(if value (from db==value on view checked="checked" else checked="")`

This is my code:

```
@{
    var District = "Apple";
 }
<div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="checkbox">
       <input type="radio" name="District" value="@Model.District)" />
               @if (District.Length==(District.Length) )
               {
                  <ul class="list-inline" style="float: right">
                     <li class="radio space">
                        <label>
                           <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Apple" checked="checked">
                        </label>
                     </li>
                     <li class="radio space">
                        <label>
                           <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Pear" checked="">
                        </label>
                     </li>
                     <li class="radio space">
                        <label>
                           <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Banana" checked="">
                        </label>
                     </li>
                     <li class="radio space">
                        <label>
                           <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Orange" checked="">
                        </label>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
               }
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a variable and put the database value in it. Then use `if{} else {}` for checking.
For example

```
<input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Orange" if(databasevalue= "on") print checked="checked" else{ print checked="" }
```

This is sample code

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set `checked` manually as it will be set automatically when the data from db equals to value of the radio.

PageModel:

```
public class RadioCheckedModel : PageModel
{
    public string District { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        District = "Apple";
    }
}
```

Page:

```
@page
@model Razor22pages.Pages.RadioCheckedModel

<h1>RadioChecked</h1>
@{
    var District = "Apple";
}
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="radio" name="District" value="@Model.District)" />
        @if (District.Length == (District.Length))
        {
            <ul class="list-inline" style="float: right">
                <li class="radio space">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Apple" >
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="radio space">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Pear">
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="radio space">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Banana" >
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="radio space">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value="Orange" >
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Xing Zou , but I went to dif solution .For the next gen Here is my workaround 
//Controller

```
    ViewBag.dis = new string[4] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
//View
 @foreach (var item in (ViewBag.dis))
                    {
                        if (item != Model.District)
                        {
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value=@item checked="">
                                <i class="fas fa-street-view"></i>@item
                            </label>
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            <i class="fas fa-street-view"></i>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" asp-for="District" value=@Model.District checked="checked">
                                <i class="fas fa-street-view"></i>@Model.District
                            </label>
                        }
                    }
```